# Is it possible to provision a Google Cloud Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancer through GKE ingress?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am using google GKE. I need an internal tcp pass-through load balancer to expose my service. The backend service can terminate TLS traffic. I could provision a tcp load balancer manually. But, I would like to manage loadbalancer through ingress. The [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) only talks about creating HTTP(S) L7 load balancer through Ingress.

Is it possible to provision a [Google Cloud Internal TCP/UDP Loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal) through GKE ingress ?

Comment: Why not just use a Service of type LoadBalancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do internal TCP load balancing, then you don't need an Ingress resource; you can just expose your deployment via a Service of type LoadBalancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ilb-service
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

The above will create an GCP Internal Load Balancer and balance incoming traffic on port 80 to your app running on port 8080.

Note:  The `networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` is what creates an ILB versus a GLB in GCP.